# Updating an ASP.NET website backend code

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

It has been several years since I have really worked with ASP.NET C# but I have a client who needs to have a simple radio box added to a form which requires more then just editing the .ascx file.

I know that they have a custom .DLL file which I assume was compiled and then uploaded and contains the codebehind files?

The file has a code behind

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PFA_Form.ascx.cs" Inherits="FLR.Controls.Input.PFA_Form" %>
```

Does this mean that if I edit the PFA_Form.ascx.cs I will have to do more then just upload that file via FTP?

As far as I know it is a Web Application Project. I have the files and solution, but Visual Studio is not connected to the web server in anyway.

Comment: If the site is compiled then any edits to the source code would need to be re-compiled and re-deployed to the server.

Comment: Whatever was done originally, you'll have to do again. In this case, that means compiling the application and deploying the changed files. In this case, the changed files will be at least the .ascx and the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a ASP.net web site you can do it by just changing the code, it will be recompiled automatically. If it's an ASP.net web application you will have to compile and deploy it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you make changes to the code behind, you will have to recompile the server side code to create a new DLL.

Comment: Again, only if it's a web application project.

Answer (score 0):

If you only had to make changes to the ascx page, then sure, you could edit it. In this case, you need to make changes to the codebehind as well, and in ASP.NET that requires you to recompile and use the new DLL.

Comment: Only if it's a web application project

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you are deploying too, you need to recompile and get the new .DLL or if its a webapp you need to right click on the main project publish, and that will give you the new deploy package.